# Dynamic Class Added By JQuery Not Triggering Click Event

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do the following:

1. Open an overlay by clicking on a div (This works)
2. Close the overlay by clicking on the same div (This doesn't work)

I'm inserting a class via JQuery after the first click and am trying to use that class to close the overlay.

I saw that dynamically generated classes need to use the .on() method in order for the click to work.

Please see code and the fiddle link that I have created below:

```
$("#nav-icon").click(function() {

    $(this).toggleClass('open');            
    $(".overlay").fadeIn(800);  

});

$('#nav-icon').on('click', '.open', function() {

    $(".overlay").fadeOut(800);

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oxd8k1nx/1/

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here please.

All help and time greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.open` is not a child of `#nav-icon`. But, it's exactly the same element

https://jsfiddle.net/oxd8k1nx/2/

```
$('body').on('click', '#nav-icon.open', function() {
```

By the way, you can do it simpler:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#nav-icon").click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
   $(".overlay").fadeOut(800);
  }
  else {
   $(".overlay").fadeIn(800);   
   }
  $(this).toggleClass('open');   
 });

});
```

```css
#container {
 
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 960px;
 
}

/* HEADER */

header {

 width: 100%;
 
}

header img {
 
 position: relative;
 
}

/* OVERLAY */

.overlay {

 background: #000;
 display: none;
 height: 100%;
 left: 0;
 padding: 30px 1%;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 50;
 
}


/* NAVIGATION */

nav {

    position: relative;
 text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
 
}

nav li {
 
 display: inline;
 margin: 0 20px 0 0;

}

nav li a {
 
 color: #fff;
 
}

#container {
 
 margin: 200px 0 0 0;
 
}

p {
 
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 26px;
 margin: 0 0 20px 0;
 
}

/* BURGER STYLES */

#nav-icon {
 
 cursor: pointer;
 height: 45px;
 position: absolute;
 right: 20px;
 top: 20px;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
 transform: rotate(0deg);
 -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
 transition: .5s ease-in-out;
 width: 60px;
 z-index: 100;
 
}

#nav-icon span {
 
 background: #eb3795;
 display: block;
 height: 9px;
 opacity: 1;
 position: absolute;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
 transform: rotate(0deg);
 -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
 transition: .25s ease-in-out;
 width: 50%;

}

#nav-icon span:nth-child(even) {
 
  border-radius: 0 9px 9px 0;
  left: 50%;

}

#nav-icon span:nth-child(odd) {
 
  border-radius: 9px 0 0 9px;
  left:0px;

}

#nav-icon span:nth-child(1), #nav-icon span:nth-child(2) {
 
  top: 0px;
  
}

#nav-icon span:nth-child(3), #nav-icon span:nth-child(4) {
 
  top: 18px;
  
}

#nav-icon span:nth-child(5), #nav-icon span:nth-child(6) {
 
  top: 36px;
  
}

#nav-icon.open span {
 
 background: #fff;
 
}

#nav-icon.open span:nth-child(1),#nav-icon.open span:nth-child(6) {
 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  
}

#nav-icon.open span:nth-child(2),#nav-icon.open span:nth-child(5) {
 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  
}

#nav-icon.open span:nth-child(1) {
 
  left: 5px;
  top: 7px;
  
}

#nav-icon.open span:nth-child(2) {
 
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
  top: 7px;
  
}

#nav-icon.open span:nth-child(3) {
 
  left: -50%;
  opacity: 0;
  
}

#nav-icon.open span:nth-child(4) {
 
  left: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  
}

#nav-icon.open span:nth-child(5) {
 
  left: 5px;
  top: 29px;
  
}

#nav-icon.open span:nth-child(6) {
 
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
  top: 29px;
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <header>

  <div class="overlay">

   <nav>

    <ul>

     <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
     <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
     <li><a href="">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
     <li><a href="">SERVICES</a></li>
     <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>

    </ul>

   </nav>
   
  </div> <!-- .overlay -->

  <div id="nav-icon">

   <span></span>
   <span></span>
   <span></span>
   <span></span>
   <span></span>
   <span></span>
   
  </div> <!-- #nav-icon -->

 </header>

 <div id="container">

  <div id="main">

   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at sapien dolor. Donec eleifend at arcu a pretium. Phasellus pulvinar placerat elit, ac fringilla risus feugiat id. Nullam rutrum sodales tellus, in sagittis libero. Mauris semper gravida dui, nec fermentum odio. Suspendisse varius sem libero, ac varius nisl molestie non. Sed nec efficitur enim. Etiam sem ex, luctus in facilisis ac, ultrices in magna. Cras dolor sapien, mollis lacinia euismod eu, convallis id ipsum. In ligula quam, sagittis et rutrum vitae, dignissim eu orci.</p>

  </div> <!-- #main -->

  <footer>

  </footer>

 </div> <!-- #container -->
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick feedback.  Not quite working as I would expect.  The first click is opening and closing the overlay.  It should just open the overlay.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In your previous code, you are calling your first handler even when there is an open class attached. So it toggles it again and thus your second handler is not fired.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('click', "#nav-icon:not('.open')", function() {
            alert(1);
        $(this).toggleClass('open');            
        $(".overlay").fadeIn(800);  

    });

    $(document).on('click', '#nav-icon.open', function() {
        alert(2);
        $(".overlay").fadeOut(800);

    });

});
```